# Question on sums of products of divisors (cont.)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, divisor-sum

In my previous [Question on sums of products of divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3951939/question-on-sums-of-products-of-divisors), I asked the following question:

**Does it exist some positive integer $n$ such that a sum of $k$ products of its divisors greater than $1$ equal $n$ itself, when $k$ is not a divisor of $n$ itself?**

An example was provided, but one of the products was less than $\sqrt{n}$. Subsequently, it came to me the following subsequent question:

**Does it exist some positive integer $n$ such that a sum of $k$ products of its divisors greater than $1$ equal $n$ itself, when $k$ is not a divisor of $n$ itself and all the products are equal or greater than $\sqrt{n}$?**

Any positive or negative answer to the question, with a counterexample, hint or sketch of a proof in the affirmative or negative direction would be really welcomed. Thanks!

**Edit**

The answer to the question is yes, as perfectly showed in the answer provided. **Would it change if we put the restriction that all the products must be distinct?**

Comment: I think the following works :$$2\cdot 3^5\cdot 7^2=2\times ( 3\times 7^2)+\sum_{j=1}^{4}(2\times 7)\times (2\times 3^j\times 7)$$where all the products are distinct, and the smallest term $2\times ( 3\times 7^2)$ is larger than $\sqrt{2\cdot 3^5\cdot 7^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you were given scales suitably.  That is, where the example had the divisors $(2,3,6,9)$ just multiply them, say, by $5$.  We get $(10,15,30,45)$ and the parallel sum is $$10\times 15+10\times 30+10\times 45+15\times 30=150+300+450+450=1350$$

Of course, $1350$ is divisible by each of $(10,15,30,45)$ and now each product is considerably greater than $\sqrt {1350}=36.742\cdots$.  And, of course, $4$ still doesn't divide $1350$.

Comment: thanks for your answer!

Comment: Now I wonder if the answer would change if we put the restriction of all the products being distinct

Comment: @JuanMoreno  There's no difficulty there, just multiply three of the factors by $5$ instead of all four.  Thus take $(10,15,30,9)$ and look at the sum $150+300+90+450=990$.